# Extract the first token from an "or list" (union) in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-inference, union-types

I want a generic type like below `F` that if:

```
type X = F<'a'|'b'|'c'>
```

then `X` should be `'a'`.

And if

```
type X = F<'alpha'|'beta'|'gamma'|'delta'>
```

then `X` should be `'alpha'`.

---

The below way **doesn't work**:

```
type F<T> = T extends (infer FirstToken | any) ? FirstToken : T
```

Test it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgPAFQHxQLxQVCAPYEB2AJgM5QAUAlvgGYQBOsFdxwCA9gNYFQA%20UAhvhABKKAH5GzVp24AuDAFgAUMtCQoADTSw4Acn67eUXQCNDfXQGNdKAPS2oAAw2OoFUo4Cu%20DvjYB3fEcAQmVlABsIYChseS10U11lIA).

Comment: if you're happy to use a tuple and pass the types into the function like `type X = F<['alpha'|'beta'|'gamma'|'delta']>` then I think its fairly simple think its called head type you can look up. If not then it's a bit weird, I think you can look up some ways to go from union to tuple but it's not recommended as the order is not guaranteed.

Comment: Tuples are conceptually unordered, and any order the compiler uses is an implementation detail.  There is no consistent way to get the "first" element.  You can get *some* element, but it might not be the one you expected.  See the answers to the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

In TS, you cant directly extract the first type from the string literal types as its not in sequence - unlike an array or a tuple.

The first concept in union doesnt exist in the language.

You can however use [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) which is used in a way to resembles extracting the "first" type from a union.

But, it's important to understand that this behaviour is a result of how TS handles conditional types, and isn't guaranteed to always work as you might expect.

[Test here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgJwM7ADwBUB8UC8UDa6AulBAB7AQB2AJkgXFQGYQJQCqUAPlAIZUh8REgH4OUAFxQqEAG6sA3AFgAUKtCQo6CCgCMuWIhSoA5LxPcoJgEYWeJgMYnMCqFAD07q%20dXrw0bRQAJgN4ZDQzABswAAtzSxsIYHj7AHNeAFsMlKsaCEjk51cPLyjYnzUVDQCdYABmUKM0KgBXDOtWSxQERlTLawB7AciIfhc3T2k2jrYAMihu3qh5weHRqlUgA)